# Two googlemaps box in the same javascript file with different locations

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps

I'm trying to find MY MISTAKE in my code:

I want to add to maps to the same script file and I was able to do that with a conditional statement but, when I get to the part of the locations and markers, I'm not able to display my pins, my info windows, and icons.

Here's my code:

```js
var map, locs;
function initMap() {
 if (document.getElementById('map')) {
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
   center: {lat: 01, lng: -01},
   zoom: 15
  });

  var image = 'http:myimage.png';

  var locations = [

  ['<div class="OzwZjf-jRmmHf-MZArnb-KDwhZb fO2voc-jRmmHf-LJTIlf"><p>My Location</p>' 49.27597, -123.1185, 1]];

  var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

  var marker, i;

  for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {  
   marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]),
    map: map,
    icon: image
   });

   google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
    return function() {
     infowindow.setContent(locations[i][0]);
     infowindow.open(map, marker);
    }
   })(marker, i));
  }
 } else if (document.getElementById('locs')) {

  locs = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('locs'), {
   center: {lat:02, lng: -02},
   zoom: 4
  });

  var image = 'http:myimage.png';

  var locations_two = [

  ['<div class="OzwZjf-jRmmHf-MZArnb-KDwhZb fO2voc-jRmmHf-LJTIlf"><p>My Location</p>' 02, -02, 1]];

  var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

  var marker_two, i;

  for (i = 0; i < locations_two.length; i++) {  
   marker_two = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations_two[i][1], locations_two[i][2]),
    map: map,
    icon: image
   });

   google.maps.event.addListener(marker_two, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
    return function() {
     infowindow.setContent(locations_two[i][0]);
     infowindow.open(map, marker);
    }
   })(marker_two, i));
  }
 }
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initMap);
```

```css
#map {height: 500px;}
#locs {height: 500px;}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<div id="map"><div>
<div id="locs"><div>
```

Both maps are in a different page, I'm able to see only the first one with locations, the second one come without location, markers and info windows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

```
marker_two = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations_two[i][1], locations_two[i][2]),
            map: map,
            icon: image
        });
```

to

```
marker_two = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations_two[i][1], locations_two[i][2]),
            map: locs,
            icon: image
        });
```

You need to use `locs` because that is the second map object that you create and that is what you need to pass while creating the marker instead of `map`.

Also 01, 02 are not valid float values. You need to change them to 1, 2 which will make them valid float numbers.

Comment: It wasn't easy to spot, I was actually able to add a third map, you solve my day!!

Comment: That's great, forgetting to change a value after copy pasting a piece of code is an issue that every developer has probably suffered. :-P